# OpenCV Assertion failed on Matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, ios, c, opencv, matrix-multiplication

I'm multiplying two matrices with OpenCV, A in NxM and B is MxP.

According to the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#cvmul):

> All the arrays must have the same type and the same size (or ROI
>   size).  For types that have limited range this operation is saturating.

However, by the [theory of matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication):

> Assume two matrices are to be multiplied (the generalization to any
>   number is discussed below). If A is an n×m matrix and B is an m×p
>   matrix, the result would be AB of their multiplication is an n×p matrix defined
>   only if the number of columns m in A is equal to the number of rows m
>   in B.

shouldn't this code be working?

```
- (CvMat *) multMatrix:(CvMat *)AMatrix BMatrix:(CvMat *)BMatrix 
{
  CvMat *result = cvCreateMat(AMatrix->rows, BMatrix->cols, kMatrixType);
  cvMul(AMatrix, BMatrix, result, 1.0);
  return result;
}
```

I get the following exception:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src1.size == dst.size &&
>   src1.channels() == dst.channels()) in cvMul, file
>   /Users/Aziz/Documents/Projects/opencv_sources/trunk/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp,
>   line 2728

kMatrixType is CV_32F, A is 6x234, B is 234x5 and result is 6x5...

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this an OpenCV restriction to matrix multiplication ?

Comment: I don't wanna be rude, but dammit! Documentation clearly states, that the matrices has to be same size, so don't ask why isn't yout code working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing element-wise multiplication with `cvMul`.

You should look at `cvMatMul` for doing proper matrix multiplication.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Matrix_operations